# Windows Batch: What does the "~" do?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was just wondering what the "~" symbol does in a batch file, I know that it's associated with variables.

Can I have some examples of what it does?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation. Look at the bottom of the help for both FOR and CALL. From the command line, type, `HELP CALL` and `HELP FOR`, or `CALL /?` AND `FOR /?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the command on which `~` is used as [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) and [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) already wrote. In general it means: Get the value of a variable (loop or environment variable) or an argument string passed to the batch file with a modification.

A very simple example:

There is a batch file `test.bat` with content:

```
@echo Parameter 1 as specified: %1
@echo Parameter 1 (no quotes):  %~1
```

which is started with

```
test.bat "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

The double quotes are necessary because of the spaces in path.

The batch file outputs:

```
Parameter 1 as specified: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Parameter 1 (no quotes):  C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

So in this example `~` results in getting value of first parameter without double quotes.

As [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) already wrote, enter in a command prompt window following commands and read the help output in the window.

1. `help call` or `call /?`
2. `help for` or `for /?`
3. `help set` or `set /?`

On many commands strings with spaces or other special characters – see last help page output after entering `cmd /?` – must be enclosed in double quotes. But others require that the double quotes are removed like on a comparison of two double quoted strings with command `if` or the double quotes are not wanted like on using `echo`.

One more example:

```
@echo off
if /I "%~n1" == "iexplore" echo Browser is Internet Explorer.
if /I "%~n1" == "opera" echo Browser is Opera.
if /I "%~n1" == "firefox" echo Browser is Firefox.
```

On this example `~n` results in just getting the file name without double quotes, path and file extension from string passed as first parameter to the batch file.

Argument 0 is the currently executed batch file as it can be demonstrated with:

```
@echo off
echo Batch file was called with: %0
echo Batch file is stored on drive:  %~d0
echo Batch file is stored in folder: %~dp0
echo Batch file name with extension: %~nx0
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context which you've not provided.

For instance, if there is a filename in %%a, then %%~za will return the filesize, %%~ta the file date/time. Other times it may be a substring operator, such as `%fred:~1,6%` (the substring of `fred`, skipping the first `1` and selecting the next `6` maximum.